# MBR not corresponding to fdisk -l?

Tags: partition, fdisk, mbr

I'm trying to map the shown with `sudo fdisk -l` and what is written in the MBR. However they seem to differ.

What `fdisk` shows:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   490612735   245305344   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       490614782   976771071   243078145    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       968929280   976771071     3920896   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       490614784   968929279   239157248   83  Linux
```

What partition table in the MBR says:

```
00001be: 8020 2100 83fe ffff 0008 0000 0020 3e1d  . !.......... >.
00001ce: 00fe ffff 05fe ffff fe2f 3e1d 0228 fa1c  ........./>..(..
00001de: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001ee: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
```

The steps for getting the MBR were:

1. `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=~/mbr.file bs=512 count=1` Getting the first 512 bytes.
2. `xxd -s 446 -l 64 mbr.file` Print just the partition tables.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the two other partitions aren't showing in MBR is because they are based on the extended partition (the type for the second partition is `0x05`.

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type#PID_0Fh